# A generic error occurred in GDI+ when calling code in nuGet package

Tags: c#, nuget-package

I am working on a program, which uses a NuGet package that saves an image from a byteArry after loading it async (with await) from the webcam. When I execute the code directly it works, but when I call the function in an other project via a NuGet package it fails by throwing a generic error in GDI+.

I read in another post in this forum that this can happen, if the byte array was not completely loaded. Thus I added a delay of 1 second before saving , but it did not help.

Can anyone tell me, why the same code does not throw an exception if I call the function direclty and not as library?

Kind regards,
Wolfgang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution for the problem: In the test program, which uses the function directly, I store the image into the directory of the executable.
In the application, which uses the function via nuget package, I stored the image into a directory, which did not exist.

So, creating all directories within the path of the image solved the problem for me :)
Therefore I am using following code:

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filename));
```

It would be good, if that could be integrated into System.Drawing.Image.Save!!